# Error loading bar chart using charts ( in swift)

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the Charts framework (by Daniel gindi). It was working fine till the latest pod re-install. Now, i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when i try

```
barChartView.data = BarChartData(...)
```

i was able to work around this issue using

```
barChartView.setValue(mybarchartData, forKey: "data")
```

However, i am doing some clean-up for the axes etc... and this seems to break for those. For example,

```
barChartView.xAxis.setValue(1, forKey:"axisLineWidth")
```

does not work. Is there something new/different for the latest release that i need to account for?

Thanks in advance!, Karthik

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by cleaning the build and re-building. Posting this in case someone else runs into the same problem.